# Alignment and centering of pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have two problems.

1. I have four pgfplots and I want to align the x-axes of the plots in the same rows, also align the y-axes of the plots on the same columns.
2. I'd like to insert a math symbol \mathcal{F}, between the plots in a row, but centered vertically between the two plots, not on the baseline.

I tried using the matrix of nodes but I'm having problems in beamer. The following is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% for plotting mathematical functions
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

% For text positioning
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphics}

% boldface math symbols
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}

% For drawing block diagrams, plotting, etc
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, quotes, backgrounds,intersections, fit, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Fourier Transform of a Rectangular Pulse}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, every node/.style={scale=1.0}]
    \begin{axis}[name=RectA, 
     xmin=-1.25, xmax = 2.5, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.25,
        axis x line=middle, height=4.0cm, width=5.0cm, 
        x axis line style={thick},
        axis y line=middle, 
        y axis line style={thick},
        %title = {Square wave},
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={$a$},
        xtick={-1.0,1.0},
        xticklabels={\scriptsize $-T\//2$,$T\//2$},
        tick style={draw=none}, 
        y tick label style={font=\small, xshift={-0.2cm},yshift={0.2cm}},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        xlabel={$\scriptstyle t$}, 
        xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.1cm}, 
        ylabel={$x(t)$}, 
        ylabel style={font=\small,yshift=0.2cm},
        ]
        \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
        coordinates
        {(-1.25,0) (-1.0,1) (1.0,1) (1.0,0) (3.75,0)};
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
$\xLongleftrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=FourierA, 
    xmin=-6*pi, xmax = 6*pi, 
    ymin = -0.25, ymax = 1.2,
    axis x line=middle, 
    height=4.5cm, width=6.0cm, 
    x axis line style={thick},  
    axis y line=middle, 
    y axis line style={thick},
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle aT$},
    xticklabels={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\scriptstyle \Omega$}, 
    xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-0.1cm}, ylabel={$\scriptstyle X(j\Omega)$}, 
    ylabel style={xshift=0.0cm},
    ]
        \addplot [red, dashed, domain = -6*pi:6*pi, samples = 100] {sin(2*x*180/pi)/(2*x) };
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, every node/.style={scale=1.0}]
\begin{axis}[name=RectB, xmin=-1.25, xmax = 2.5, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.25,
        axis x line=middle, height=4.0cm, width=5.0cm, 
        x axis line style={thick},
        axis y line=middle, 
        y axis line style={thick},
        %title = {Square wave},
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={$a$},
        xtick={-0.25,0.25},
        xticklabels={\scriptsize $-\tfrac{T}{8}$,$\tfrac{T}{8}$},
        tick style={draw=none}, 
        y tick label style={font=\small, xshift={-0.2cm},yshift={0.2cm}},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        xlabel={$\scriptstyle t$}, 
        xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.1cm}, 
        ylabel={$x(t)$}, 
        ylabel style={font=\small,yshift=0.2cm},
        ]
        \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
        coordinates
        {(-1.25,0) (-0.25,0) (-0.25,1) (0.25,1) (0.25,0) (3.75,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
$\xLongleftrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, every node/.style={scale=1.0}]
\begin{axis}[name=FourierB, xmin=-6*pi, xmax = 6*pi, 
    ymin = -0.25, ymax = 1.2,
    axis x line=middle, 
    height=4.5cm, width=6.0cm, 
    x axis line style={thick},  
    axis y line=middle, 
    y axis line style={thick},
    ytick={0.25},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle  aT\//4$},
    xticklabels={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\scriptstyle \Omega$}, 
    xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-0.1cm}, ylabel={$\scriptstyle X(j\Omega)$}, 
    ylabel style={xshift=0.0cm},
    ]
        \addplot [red, dashed, domain = -6*pi:6*pi, samples = 100] {0.25*sin(0.5*x*180/pi)/(0.5*x) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `tikzpicture` option `[scale=1.0, every node/.style={scale=1.0}]` hasn't any influence on picture. It would be better to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, and position the axes relative to the other using the `at` key, some shifting, and the various `origin` anchors. For example, for the `FourierA` axis, use

```
at={(RectA.right of origin)},
xshift=1cm,
anchor=left of origin,
```

Those anchors are described in section 4.19 *Alignment options* of the `pgfplots` manual. Basically, `left of origin` is on the left side of the axis, at the same height as the origin. Similarly for `right of`/`above`/`below`.

Hence, the code above will place the `left of origin` anchor of the `FourierA` axis on the `right of origin` anchor of `RectA`, but shifted 1cm right. Modify 1cm to whatever you prefer.

To place the arrows, make a path between the two axes, and add the node to that path, e.g.

```
\path (RectA) -- node{$\xLongleftrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$} (FourierA);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% for plotting mathematical functions
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

% For text positioning
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphics}

% boldface math symbols
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}

% For drawing block diagrams, plotting, etc
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, quotes, backgrounds,intersections, fit, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, every node/.style={scale=1.0}]
    \begin{axis}[name=RectA, 
     xmin=-1.25, xmax = 2.5, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.25,
        axis x line=middle, height=4.0cm, width=5.0cm, 
        x axis line style={thick},
        axis y line=middle, 
        y axis line style={thick},
        %title = {Square wave},
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={$a$},
        xtick={-1.0,1.0},
        xticklabels={\scriptsize $-T\//2$,$T\//2$},
        tick style={draw=none}, 
        y tick label style={font=\small, xshift={-0.2cm},yshift={0.2cm}},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        xlabel={$\scriptstyle t$}, 
        xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.1cm}, 
        ylabel={$x(t)$}, 
        ylabel style={font=\small,yshift=0.2cm},
        ]
        \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
        coordinates
        {(-1.25,0) (-1.0,1) (1.0,1) (1.0,0) (3.75,0)};
    \end{axis}%
    
    \begin{axis}[
    at={(RectA.right of origin)},
    xshift=1cm,
    anchor=left of origin,
    name=FourierA, 
    xmin=-6*pi, xmax = 6*pi, 
    ymin = -0.25, ymax = 1.2,
    axis x line=middle, 
    height=4.5cm, width=6.0cm, 
    x axis line style={thick},  
    axis y line=middle, 
    y axis line style={thick},
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle aT$},
    xticklabels={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\scriptstyle \Omega$}, 
    xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-0.1cm}, ylabel={$\scriptstyle X(j\Omega)$}, 
    ylabel style={xshift=0.0cm},
    ]
        \addplot [red, dashed, domain = -6*pi:6*pi, samples = 100] {sin(2*x*180/pi)/(2*x) };
    \end{axis}%
    
\begin{axis}[name=RectB,
      at={(RectA.below origin)},
      yshift=-1cm,
      anchor=above origin,
       xmin=-1.25, xmax = 2.5, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 1.25,
        axis x line=middle, height=4.0cm, width=5.0cm, 
        x axis line style={thick},
        axis y line=middle, 
        y axis line style={thick},
        %title = {Square wave},
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={$a$},
        xtick={-0.25,0.25},
        xticklabels={\scriptsize $-\tfrac{T}{8}$,$\tfrac{T}{8}$},
        tick style={draw=none}, 
        y tick label style={font=\small, xshift={-0.2cm},yshift={0.2cm}},
        x tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        xlabel={$\scriptstyle t$}, 
        xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.1cm}, 
        ylabel={$x(t)$}, 
        ylabel style={font=\small,yshift=0.2cm},
        ]
        \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
        coordinates
        {(-1.25,0) (-0.25,0) (-0.25,1) (0.25,1) (0.25,0) (3.75,0)};
    \end{axis}

\begin{axis}[name=FourierB,
    at={(RectB.right of origin)},
    xshift=1cm,
    anchor=left of origin,
    xmin=-6*pi, xmax = 6*pi, 
    ymin = -0.25, ymax = 1.2,
    axis x line=middle, 
    height=4.5cm, width=6.0cm, 
    x axis line style={thick},  
    axis y line=middle, 
    y axis line style={thick},
    ytick={0.25},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle  aT\//4$},
    xticklabels={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\scriptstyle \Omega$}, 
    xlabel style={xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-0.1cm}, ylabel={$\scriptstyle X(j\Omega)$}, 
    ylabel style={xshift=0.0cm},
    ]
        \addplot [red, dashed, domain = -6*pi:6*pi, samples = 100] {0.25*sin(0.5*x*180/pi)/(0.5*x) };
    \end{axis}
    
\path (RectA) -- node{$\xLongleftrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$} (FourierA);
\path (RectB) -- node{$\xLongleftrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$} (FourierB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.